# Power shell script to clear RDP connection history from registry

Tags: powershell, registry, rdp

I am new to Powershell but I have stuck in one place that is elaborate in the following details.

I want to perform a PowerShell script in which it will delete the **RDP connection history** from the **registry** **(MRU number)** but it will not delete all history, first, it will check one by one file and ask for approving whether to delete or not then deletion process will start. and after completion of the deletion process, it will restart the server again.

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax will cycle through all 10 possible entries and ask you Y/N to delete them individually. Note that Windows only retains a max of 10 entries. Also note that Windows also retains similar data in "\documents\default.rdp", so this file should be deleted as part of your process.

```
@echo off
SET count=0
 :AGAIN
 reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default" /s | findstr "MRU%count%"
 if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default" /v "MRU%count%") ELSE (goto ExitScript)
 set /a count+=1
 if %count% GEQ 10 GOTO ExitScript
 GOTO AGAIN
 :ExitScript
```